# Displaying multiple custom post types in single post type at admin section

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I want to display different custom posts types in single post in admin section. how i can accomplish this. I have 3 posts which are Events, Members and Guests. I want to display these 3 posts like this.

Custom post of {Events}
    Custom Posts of attending registered {users} for corrosponding event 
          Custom posts of non-registered {guests}.

I've done till first step displaying custom posts{Events} by registering post type {Events} with default columns.

Here is my code..

```
function events_custom_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Eventss', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'mesocolumn' ),
);


$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Events', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Events for visiting members', 'mesocolumn' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => null,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);

register_post_type( 'Events', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'events_custom_post_type', 0 );
```

But now how to get data for remaining two custom posts. Please give me some idea and also kindly, let me know to add jquery to this displayed tags. I want to use jquery to this displayed html content tags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Why would this not be the right place? 2) What "post is related to [your] requirement"? 3) Where is your code? Post it please. 4) This is potentially very, very server resource intensive/

Comment: Sorry.. S_HA_DUM.. I placed this content in under someone's post but later i deleted due to improper place & placed new post for this but forgot to remove that content.

Comment: You have a bit of a project. Try reading some of these: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin+post+table